# Proving that $c_0$ with the norm $\|x\|= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_n|}{2^n}$ is not Banach

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Denoting $c_0 = \{(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} : \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0 \}$, I want to prove that the normed space $(c_0, \| \cdot \|)$ is not a Banach space, where $\|x\|= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_n|}{2^n}$ . 
I know that I need to find a Cauchy sequence in $c_0$ that converges to an element that does not belong in $c_0$, but I'm stuck. 
I've tried using the sequence $(n/k)_{k=1}^{\infty} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, which is a Cauchy sequence, but I don't think it works. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would take $x^{(m)}=(1, 2, 3, \dots, m, 0, \dots)$. Then $(x^{(m)})_{m\geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence, but does not converge.

Comment: @Gae.S. I fixed it.

Comment: What kind of numbers are $x_n$? Integers, rational numbers o real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sequence $X_{k,n}$ defined as $1$ for $n\leq k$ and $0$ for $n>k$. Then obviously $X_{k,n}\in c_0$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$. In addition $X_{k,n}\stackrel{||\cdot||}{\longrightarrow}X_{\infty,n}$ defined as $1$ for every $n\in\mathbb N$. However $X_{\infty,n}\not\in c_0$.

Comment: What does the fact that $X_{k,n}$ converges to a sequence $X_{\infty,n}$ in a *different* normed space, namely the subspace of the real-valued sequences $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\lvert y_n\rvert}{2^n}<\infty$ endowed with the norm $\lVert x\rVert=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\lvert x_n\rvert}{2^n}$, have to do with whether or not there is a sequence in $Y\in (c_0,\lVert \cdot\rVert)$ such that $X_{k,n}\to Y$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $||x|| \leq ||x||_\infty$ for all $x \in c_0$. Suppose $(c_0, ||.||)$ was complete, then by the open mapping theorem $||.|| $ and $|| .|| _\infty$ are equivalent. Take a look at the sequence $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$, where $e_n(k) =1$ iff $k=n$.

Comment: I think your sequence $(e_n)_{n\geq 1}$ converges in $\Vert .\Vert$ to the zero sequence.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But $||e_n||_\infty=1 $ for all n

Comment: Ahh, you want to back up the claim that $c_0$ is not complete in the sup-norm. I thought you want to give an alternative solution by providing an explicite Cauchy sequence that does not converge in $\Vert . \Vert$.

Comment: Basically, if $c_0$ was complete w.r.t. $||.||$, then $|| . || $ and $|| .||_\infty$ would be equivalent. But $ ||e_n||_\infty  \to 1$ and $||e_n|| \to 0$, which leads to a contradiction

Comment: Yes, yes, I know :) should have read more carefully.